Problems when solving a modified version of the taxi environment with PPO
I am currently working on solving a simplified/modified version of the Taxi-V3 problem from gymnasium.
Specifically, the modified problem is as follows:
I have an agent (the taxidriver) which is operating in a 5x5 fully observable gridworld. Within this gridworld, customers appear randomly somewhere on the map and disappear after a certain amount of time if not picked up.The goal of the agent is to serve as many customers as possible by picking them up and dropping them off at some fixed location (this location is one specific cell and equal for all customers). Sucessfully completing a customer's request earns the agent a reward of 15 (equally split between 7.5 for a successfull pick up and 7.5 for a successfull drop-off). Movement (up, down, left, right) incures a negative reward of -1, while not doing anything at all (i.e., staying in the current cell) earns a reward of 0. The agent can only pick up one customer at a time and starts each episode at the target location.
I have implemented PPO to solve this specific problem but have troubles making it work. Whenever I run training, the agent has problems finding the right strategy and does not really understand what to do.
I believe that I either messed something up within the implementation of PPO or the way that I defined the state is problematic and does not capture everything that is relevant. This is what I currently have as state:
    def get_obs(self):
    agent_pos = self.agent_loc
    free_capacity = self.agent_capacity - self.agent_load
    item_locs = list.copy(self.item_locs)
    item_times = [(self.max_response_time - i) for i in list.copy(self.item_times)]

    # Zero Padding for fixed number of items (24)
    while len(item_locs) < 24:
        item_locs.append((-10000, -10000))
        item_times.append(0)

    obs = np.concatenate([np.array(agent_pos).flatten(), np.array([free_capacity]), np.array(item_locs).flatten(), np.array(item_times).flatten()])

    return obs

And here you can find the full code to my PPO implementation and training if needed:
https://pastebin.com/Fbiap4cu
Does anyone here have a clue what a possible solution to this problem might be (i.e., what a good state represetation is, what kind of architecture to use, is the code faulty, ...)?
